# Fantasy movie with lizardmen coming out of the ground

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a fantastic movie from the 70's, or 80's, maybe early 90's.

Various groups are sent on a search for an artifact; I think it was a sword. There is one scene I can remember quite clear: A group of riders is stopped by some kind of lizardmen coming out of the ground in front of them where they have been hiding in the middle of the path.
Another scene plays in some sort of cave with fog on the ground.

Comment: That's not much to go on. Do you remember what language it was in? Did you see it in a cinema or on TV? Were there special effects? Was the setting rather like Antiquity, or medieval, or more recent?

Comment: I am sorry I really don't remember, The most obvious scene I have in my mind are those weird lizardmen that suddenly come out of the ground and stop the group. I think it was something like a competition to get this magic sword or artifact.

Comment: @akatemple - It sounds alot like Dragonlance but that is a book series and never quite made it to a movie.  
That said this is not nearly enough information and you would porobably be better served looking through IMDB.

Comment: I know it sounds like Dragonlance, I love those books but that is definitely what I am thinking of.  Also there is an animated movie of The Dragons of Twilight, Kiefer Sutherland does the voice of Raistlin.

Comment: I know this is ancient and resolved, but I got here with the same question, and in my case it was not Krull. So for the benefit of others in my situation: After some more digging and watching, the film I had in mind turned out to be "The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire" from 1981, which indeed also has lizardmen popping up in an ambush in an early scene, and a finale set in a foggy cave.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Krull*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_%28film%29). Good flick and made into an [Atari game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(video_game)) back in the day. The artifact appears to be the "Glaive" from the Wikipedia description.

> Prince Colwyn is found and nursed by Ynyr, the Old One. Ynyr tells him the Beast can be defeated with the "Glaive", an ancient, magical, five-pointed throwing weapon. Colwyn retrieves the Glaive from a high mountain cave before setting out to track down the Black Fortress, which teleports to a new location every day at sunrise. As they travel, Colwyn and Ynyr are joined by magician Ergo "the Magnificent" and a band of nine thieves, fighters, bandits and brawlers. Colwyn offers to clear their criminal records, successfully enlisting Torquil, Kegan, Rhun, Oswyn, Bardolph, Menno, Darro, Nennog and Quain. The cyclops Rell later joins the group.