# 70s-80s movie: crossbowmen get ambushed by lizardmen when looking for an artifact/sword

Tags: story-identification, movie

Someone else [sought help with identifying a film they remembered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13329/19561). I think I remember the same film, but I don't think it is the film they accepted as their answer — [*Krull*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_%28film%29) (1983).

From their description I can clearly see this scene

> Various groups are sent on a search for an artifact. I think it was a sword. There is one scene I can remember quite clear: a group of riders is stopped by some kind of lizardmen coming out of the ground in front of them where they have been hiding in the middle of the path. Another scene plays in some sort of cave with fog on the ground.

I remember the ground during the ambush was covered in yellow leaves or something that gave the appearance of autumn. I think they had energy crossbows.

Can anyone help with this? I can't think of the film's title. I think it's early '80s. Late '70s is possible; for sure not '90s.

Comment: I'm confused. You've copied details over from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13329/fantasy-movie-from-70s-or-80s-maybe-early-90s) which OP has confirmed ***is*** Krull.

Comment: @Valorum Seems clear to me. OP remembers this scene as well, adds some additional details, but is certain, that that scene isn't from Krull.

Comment: @Dulkan the user is saying they're looking for a film with the exact same details, but it's not the film the other person was looking for. It can be seen as confusing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include things that you remember that are definitely **not** in *Krull*? In other words, why are you convinced that *Krull* is the wrong movie?

Comment: "The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire" (1981 TV movie)? It has a scene just like this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mistaken and it was *Krull* after all. Here's the relevant scene of battle in the swamp.

Note that the ground is indeed yellowish, which, together with the bare trees, gives an autumn-like appearance. Also note the energy weapons that look a bit like crossbows at first.